# Coding support/ resistance using mql4 language

Tags: mql4

Pls what step should I apply in writing a code that can draw support and resistance level in a chart using mql4

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to know how to find s/r levels or how to draw levels on a chart?

Answer (score 0):

You achieve drawing a support or resistance line by creating an `OBJ_HLINE` type graphical object at some given price. Here is an example:

```
ObjectCreate(0, "Support1", OBJ_HLINE, 0, 0, Price);
```

where `Support1` is just some text name, and `Price` is some price level.